# Digitally adjusting AC voltage for a motor

Tags: motor, ac, voltage-regulator, fan, thyristor

Basically I have an extraction fan motor that runs full speed at 230V, at 130V it runs around half the speed. The original chip allows switching between few voltages (and therefore, fan speeds) upon installation (a button on the board).

I would like to make it digitally controlled from intranet. For the signal handling and sending I'll be using Arduino/ESP/STM32 or similar chip since I have experience with those.

Now the hard part for me is to make AC from 230V to smaller ones, like 130V, dynamically. I can see that original chip uses a thyristor which is hooked to some sort of microcontroller.

I searched this stackexchange before posting and found people mainly recommending AC-AC transformers, like variac. But I think that would be an overkill for my problem.

I found that there are SCR regulators specifically for AC motors. The problem is that either they have a potentiometer as the control mechanism or are really bulky. To use first one I would need to desolder the physical potentiometer and change it with digital one, but my quick research suggested that digital potentiometers mainly are used for low voltages.

Then there are dimmers. But I found out that dimmers are good for lights but bad for motors.

Then there are most basic transistors and thyristors. It seems that most SCR boards uses thyristors and the original fan board uses it too. But from what I understand it is not as easy to connect it to Arduino or ESP32.

The fan uses ~6w of power only, so no need for a fancy bulky device which can handle 5kW, even 100w in my case is rather an overkill.

Maybe you have a suggestion what to use in my case and how to hook it up to 3.3v or 5v control device?

Comment: DC fans are more efficient and often quieter. Why not look for a 5W 12V Fan?  Why internet controlled instead of automatic temperature-controlled?

Comment: Well it's air extraction fan in bathroom. By default you wire it to the light switch, so most of them are 230V. But in my case lights are controlled via internet (HomeAssistant). And the fan is not always needed when the light is on, and it is sometimes (not always) needed when the light is off. I have a bunch of sensors already connected to HA, so it is more convenient that way. The exact fan was chosen for 3 reasons: a) how much air it pushes (up to 120m3/h); b) design of the casing; and c) available locally. At 100% it is quite loud (~35db) but more like strong-wind loud, at 50% it's ~16db.